# BigQuery ST_DWITHIN multiple points with multiple points

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

So I've got N points to consider and M points for reference.
I'm trying to filter all the Points in N, that are within some radius R of any of the M points.

For the following example, my-table-1 is a table with ids and single coordinate GEOGRAPHY entries

Currently im only able to get this working for N to 1 Point using something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'my-table-1' as one
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(points, (SELECT points FROM 'my-table-1' WHERE id = '1234'), 10000)
```

So basically what im trying to accomplish is that same statement but using multiple points to compare.
What I want is basically this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'my-table-1' as one
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(points, (SELECT points FROM 'my-table-1' WHERE id IN('1234', '2345', ...)), 10000)
```

But this results in a error because ST_DWITHIN can only compare 1 point to N points. I tried looking into BQ LOOPS and ARRAYS but couldnt figure out a solution so far.
The exact error im getting in the second statement is `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`

Basically comparing all points with a set of specific points in the same table and check if they are within some radius around those

Comment: I'm lost.   You are joining on `id`, so what is being compared?  Are the geographies consisting of multiple points?  Or are the multiple points in different columns?  Or in arrays?

Comment: no im trying to compare ALL points to specific points filtered out by ids.
So i've got ids, i take rows with certain ids. then compare ALL points to the points that correspond to the specific ids and see if they are within a certain range

Comment: my-table-1 has a column of geographies with 1 point each. a column of points called "points". Im trying to filter out "points" that are within certain points of the same column

Comment: . . Why does your sample code join on `id`?  Why does it join at all?

Comment: Because thats as close to my real code as i could get it to be. but thats completely besides the point, i dont know why you are making such a big deal out of it. i edited that part out so i hope the main question becomes more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to filter all the Points in N, that are within some radius R of any of the M points.

The way to work with two tables is via JOIN. Your query

```
SELECT *
FROM 'my-table-1' as one
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(points, (SELECT points FROM 'my-table-1' WHERE id IN ...), 10000)
```

Should become

```
SELECT one.id, one.points
FROM 'my-table-1' one JOIN 'my-table-1' two
ON ST_DWITHIN(one.points, two.points, 10000)
WHERE two.id IN ('1234', '2345', ...)
```

Note this will produce duplicate points, if some point from `one` is within 10km of several points in `two`. So you'll probably want to remove duplicates, I would add `GROUP BY` for this (this assumes we have some unique column `id`):

```
SELECT id, ANY_VALUE(points) AS points
FROM (
  SELECT one.id, one.points
  FROM 'my-table-1' one JOIN 'my-table-1' two
  ON ST_DWITHIN(one.points, two.points, 10000)
  WHERE two.id IN ('1234', '2345', ...)
)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: That's a nice query. Is it possible to use: 
```SELECT DISTINCT(one.id) FROM ...``` and ditch the first SELECT and GROUP clause?

Comment: Yes, if one only needs ids - the `DISTINCT` should be a better choice. AFAIK BigQuery does not support DISTINCT geographies though.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i did not realize you could use ST_DWITHIN inside the join on statement. that makes a lot more sense yea

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the case correctly I would probably:

- Create a buffer with radius R around the M points (ST_Buffer)
- Union those geometries (ST_Union)
- Select from the N points using ST_DWithin on the N points and the union/buffer geometry

This is from the top of my head, I can't construct the query in my mind though, but I think a single query should do it or you could throw a WITH statement there.

Let me know if that works for you. I saw that for BigQuery you have no ST_Buffer, but you can use jslibs.turf.ST_BUFFER instead.

Edit: Damn, I just realized this is not a PG question, but a BQ question...
Shame on me. Are those functions available there?

Here's an example PG query (tested):

```
select n.id from "N_Points" as n, (select st_buffer(m.geom, 20000) as geom 
from "M_Points" m where m.id < 10) as p
where st_dwithin(n.geom, p.geom, 0);
```

where 20000 is the radius (R) in projection units and geom is the geometry/geography column.
You can replace it with a join or use a "with" clause instead of that long select st_buffer.
Looks like you don't even need to Union those geometries. :)
You can use ST_Within too:

```
ST_Within(n.geom, p.geom)
```

Comment: But even PostGIS doc for ST_Buffer says this: `People often make the mistake of using this function to try to do radius searches. Creating a buffer to a radius search is slow and pointless. Use ST_DWithin instead.` So why buffer and pass 0 to st_dwithin, when you can pass the radius to st_dwithin and avoid buffer?

Comment: I agree, this would look and perform better with the join
```select n.id from "N_Points" as n
join "M_Points" m on
st_dwithin(n.geom, m.geom, 20000)
where m.id < 10;```
That was my initial intention, I wanted to explore other possiblities.
Thank you.